IndexError: index 26328703 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 26328059
So, I am falling onto this error all the time with this project I'm doing. I am building a recommendation system based on a very large data frame, and the error occurs in this function:
 def preprocess_data(sampled_data):
    e# Reset index to ensure uniqueness
    sampld_data = sampled_data.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    # Pivot the dataframe to create user-item interaction matrix
    user_item_matrix = sampled_data.pivot(index='srch_id', columns='prop_id', values='booking_bool').fillna(0)
    
    return user_item_matrix

user_item_matrix = preprocess_data(sampled_data)

The data is actually cleaned and processed in chunks, but I still don't get what I was expecting. I am a noob at programming

After cleaning and processing the data, are sure that the size is still the same?

@MaksymAndreiev thanks for caring, there are some variables (columns) added but all data has the same rows. The rows are like more than 5 million whereas the columns are around 20
